# Coloring ordered list items above 10+

Tags: jquery, html, css

When using this method to color numbers of ordered list items:

```
  ol {
    padding-left:0;
    >li {
      list-style-type: none;
      counter-increment: list;
      position: relative;
      padding-left: 30px;
      &:before {
        content: counter(list) ".";
        position: absolute;
        left: 5px;
      }
    }
  }
```

When reaching double digits you get this issue when number gets too close to the text: http://d.pr/i/IDh8r7
Anyway make it so it doesnt happen and not just adding more padding?

Comment: `Anyway make it so it doesnt happen and not just adding more padding?` Nope. You just have to add more padding. I'm not sure what you would be looking for in an alternative solution?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Idea was just to color numbers, and this seemed simple way to do it. I suppose going over 10 items will probably need another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that like this instead, where you align it from the right

```css
ol {
  padding-left: 0;
}

ol>li {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-increment: list;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

ol>li:before {
  content: counter(list) ".";
  position: absolute;
  /* right: calc(100% - 25px);              this is the same as "left: 5px"  */
  right: calc(100% - 20px);             /*  this will probably look better   */
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about some `text-align: right` on the numbers ? I know it's not necessarily what you asked for, but it would be much more visually pleasing.

Comment: That won't work unless you also give the pseudo element a width

Comment: Was just an idea thrown in the wind and the answer before mine is much better anyway, but thank you for the precision!

Comment: I asked an question please can you check it ?
this is the url
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45008621/parent-div-not-getting-height-if-child-div-is-absolute/45008670#45008670