# Parent div Not getting height if child div is absolute

Tags: html, css, css-position

I just stuck in `position`, I used `position:relative` for parent and `position:absolute` for child now parent div did't get height and i don't want to use `min-height` or `height`. You can see the red `border` on top which is the parent div `border`.

**[fiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/f8ugb7c8/)**

```css
.box {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda adipisci vel, dolore aspernatur iste iure blanditiis quam esse repudiandae aperiam debitis doloribus necessitatibus placeat tempora voluptate totam exercitationem neque quae.
  </div>
</div>
```

Help me please ?

Thanks

Comment: CSS 101: Absolute positioning takes an element out of normal flow, so that it _can not_ influence the measures of its parent any more. _“Anyone help me to how i get it ?”_ - get _what_? You completely neglected to describe what you actually want to achieve here.

Comment: I want to get parent div height here i mansion it over the question summery

Comment: Well then you don’t want to use absolute positioning, because as I just told you, that makes it impossible.

Comment: ... or if you have to use absolute, than add some Javascript, there is no other way.

Answer (score 1):

You could just make the outer box absolute, if your textbos has to be positioned absolute.

EDIT: Without being able to edit the HTML structure, you need specific heights or some JavaScript. [More Information about position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

```css
.box {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
}

.content {
  width: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda adipisci vel, dolore aspernatur iste iure blanditiis quam esse repudiandae aperiam debitis doloribus necessitatibus placeat tempora voluptate totam exercitationem neque quae.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No the structure will  same the `content` div will absolute and the parent will `relative`.

Comment: Then you have to use specific heights or need to write som JS for this, because an absolute positioned element is detached from the flow

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible without javascript but you can get this if add a child element inside the '.content'...

```css
.box {
  text-align: center;
  
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
.inner{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
  <div class="inner">   
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda adipisci vel, dolore aspernatur iste iure blanditiis quam esse repudiandae aperiam debitis doloribus necessitatibus placeat tempora voluptate totam exercitationem neque quae.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolute positioning takes an element out of normal flow, so it can not change the measures of its parent any more. Try this, it works fine:

```
.box {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 500px;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.content {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```